# How to convert commandline "key=value" args to dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, args

Currently I need to implement a python program that takes an arbitrary number of commandline arguments like

```
python myprog.py x1=12 y3=hello zz=60
```

and the arguments need to be converted into a dictionary like

```
{"x1": "12", "y3": "hello", "zz": "60"}
```

I tried the *argparse* module, but the keys in the arguments (x1, y3, zz in the example) cannot be known beforehand, while *argparse* seems to need me to add the argument keys individually, so I don't think it fits this specific situation?

Any idea how to accomplish this kind of commandline args to dictionary conversion, have I missed something about *argparse* or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just parse it by processing the strings. e.g.

```
import sys

kw_dict = {}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if '=' in arg:
        sep = arg.find('=')
        key, value = arg[:sep], arg[sep + 1:]
        kw_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: Should probably do `for arg in sys.argv[1:]:`, since the program name should never be a useful argument. Also, using `key, sep, value = arg.partition('=')` will allow the value to contain an equals sign without causing an exception.

Comment: noted. I guess the main problem with my old code was that it cannot handle more than one equal signs. updated code.